# Can't update migrated taxonomy terms because of langcode

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

We have a site that we migrated from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8.  If we try to update (Just edit and save) one of the terms that were migrated over, we get an error "The value you selected is not a valid choice.". If we add a new term we get no errors.

I tracked it down to the langcode field but not sure how to fix. This is somehow added automatically in Drupal.  One thing that I did notice is that in the `taxonomy_term_data` table, the langcode was blank for the ones that were migrated but the new ones have `en`.  I updated all to `en` but the problem remains.